# Formatting Lines of Text in specific order - terminal

Tags: ubuntu, text, terminal, formatting

Matching the bottom block of text with the top block of text, with some other formatting requirements.

Below is an excerpt of the block of the text, this is repeated in a large file.

```
 B. Silva
 MID MAN CITY
 A. Robertson
 DEF LIVERPOOL
 A. Lacazette
 ST ARSENAL
 C. Azpilicueta
 DEF CHELSEA
 . Alisson
 GK LIVERPOOL
 L. Sane
 MID MAN CITY
 P. Pogba
 MID MAN UTD
 K. Walker
 DEF MAN CITY
 M. Alonso
 DEF CHELSEA
 R. Jimenez
 ST WOLVES
 G. Jesus
 ST MAN CITY
 H. Son
 ST SPURS
 M. Doherty
 DEF WOLVES
 R. Firmino
 ST LIVERPOOL
 Ederson
 GK MAN CITY
 D. Silva
 MID MAN CITY PRICE GW PTS AVG PTS TOTAL
 PTS SELECTED %
 £4.7m - 4.5 223 19%
 £4.6m 8 4.6 221 38.8%
 £5.3m - 4.5 219 15.1%
 £4.3m - 3.8 210 14.2%
 £4.2m 13 4.1 209 25.8%
 £5.7m - 4.4 204 18.6%
 £5.1m - 4.2 199 22.5%
 £4.7m - 3.8 196 19.8%
 £4.8m - 5.1 193 17.8%
 £4.8m - 4.4 193 4.8%
 £4.9m - 4.2 192 9.8%
 £5.2m 0 3.9 189 10%
 £4.5m - 4.2 189 10.6%
 £4.8m 0 3.8 183 16.3%
 £4.2m - 3.2 178 26.8%
 £3.8m - 3.5 176 9.4%
```

I'd like it to be formatted in the following way:

```
B. Silva, MID, MAN CITY, £4.7m - 4.5 223 19%
A. Robertson, DEF, LIVERPOOL, £4.6m 8 4.6 221 38.8%
```

Comment: FYI, the large file repeats this order. And im using Ubuntu cmd line

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in the end:

The unneeded text ( MID MAN CITY PRICE GW PTS AVG PTS TOTAL & PTS SELECTED % ) I grepped out firstly

```
$ cat stats.txt | grep -v "PTS" > file.txt
```

Grep just the points using the £ as an identified

```
$ cat file.txt | grep £ > points.txt

$ cat file.txt | grep -v £ > playersandteams.txt
```

I then used a macro in Notepat++ to get the players and teams on the same line. Then used cut with a space delimeter to separate them out. Long way round I know...

Then I copied them all into a spreadsheet as that's how I thought best to represent the data. I'm sure there's a way to do this, but would require a bash/python script I think to create a line pointer.